# My interface freezes when performing another task asynchronously

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin, uwp

Sorry for my English

I call my page, which is called "MessagePage", which contains the method of initializing the components "this.InitializeComponent();".

And I create a method that is called when loading the page, called "Page_Loaded".

In this method there is a call to another method, which will load a mass of data to fill a grid in the interface, and this method can take 10 seconds to be executed.

However, my interface is frozen until this method responds.

I wanted the interface to become usual while data is requested.

```
public MessagePage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {await PopulateGrid();}

private async Task PopulateGrid() { //my code}
```

I already appreciate the help.

Comment: You'll need to show us what `PopulateGrid` actually does. Just because it's `async` doesn't mean it will run on a non-gui thread.

Comment: I use a While, waiting for a UDP connection to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a task in the While that is waiting for an answer. Like this:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (!result)
                {
                    if (startTime.AddSeconds(10) < DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
```